# jQuery animations step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem on my jQuery animation.
I want a button which change the width of a div from 100% to 72.5%. Next to this div could be another div which could fill the rest space (width 22.5%, 5% margin)
It could do following things step by step:

- Div 1 get a border
- div 1 change his width
- div 2 get opacity and change his width

Here is my code:

```
var hidden = true;
        function openEditMenu(){
            var em = document.getElementById("editMenu");
            var rf = document.getElementById("reportField");
            if(hidden){
                $({alpha:0}).animate({alpha:1}, {
                    duration: 1500,
                    step: function(){
                        rf.style.border ="1px solid rgba(0,0,0,"+this.alpha+")";
                    }
                }); 
                $("#editMenu").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0},1000);

                $(em).animate({width: "22.5%"},{ duration: 1000, queue: false });
                $(rf).animate({width: "72.5%"},{ duration: 1000, queue: false });
                $(rf).animate({marginRight: "5%"},{ duration: 1000, queue: false });

            }
            else{
                $({alpha:1}).animate({alpha:0}, {
                duration: 1000,
                    step: function(){
                        rf.style.border ="1px solid rgba(0,0,0,"+this.alpha+")";
                    }
                }); 


                $(em).animate({width: "0%"},{ duration: 1000, queue: false });
                $(rf).animate({width: "100%"},{ duration: 1000 });
                $(rf).animate({marginRight: "0%"},{ duration: 1000, queue: false });
                $("#editMenu").css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0.0},1000);
            }   
            hidden = !hidden;
        }
```

Like you can see in the example now everything happens on the same time. But I want that everything works step by step.

```js
var hidden = true;

function openEditMenu() {
  var em = document.getElementById("editMenu");
  var rf = document.getElementById("reportField");
  if (hidden) {
    $({
      alpha: 0
    }).animate({
      alpha: 1
    }, {
      duration: 1500,
      step: function() {
        rf.style.border = "1px solid rgba(0,0,0," + this.alpha + ")";
      }
    });
    $("#editMenu").css({
      opacity: 0.0,
      visibility: "visible"
    }).animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);

    $(em).animate({
      width: "22.5%"
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue: false
    });
    $(rf).animate({
      width: "72.5%"
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue: false
    });
    $(rf).animate({
      marginRight: "5%"
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue: false
    });

  } else {
    $({
      alpha: 1
    }).animate({
      alpha: 0
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      step: function() {
        rf.style.border = "1px solid rgba(0,0,0," + this.alpha + ")";
      }
    });


    $(em).animate({
      width: "0%"
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue: false
    });
    $(rf).animate({
      width: "100%"
    }, {
      duration: 1000
    });
    $(rf).animate({
      marginRight: "0%"
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue: false
    });
    $("#editMenu").css({
      opacity: 1.0,
      visibility: "visible"
    }).animate({
      opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000);
  }
  hidden = !hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:inline-flex;width:100%;">
  <div id="reportField" style="width:100%; height:50px; background-color:blue;">
    a
  </div>
  <div id="editMenu" style="width:0%; height:50px; background-color:red; visibility: hidden;">
    b
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="openEditMenu()">

</button>
```

I know this solution:

```
$('#id').animate(
    { left: new value },
     duration, function() {
       // Animation complete.
  });
```

But it doesnt works on my alpha animation.

Comment: Have you tried just setting your `queue: false` to `queue: true`?

Comment: yes that makes all animation of the same object step by step. but i need the same for two objects.